# EF consistency between two or more reads

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions) page in Microsoft's documentation on EF it is stated literally

> Entity Framework does not wrap queries in a transaction

If I am right, this means that sql reads are not implied with transactions and thus every select in our code is executed independently. But if this is so, can we ensure that two reads are consistent between each other? In the typical scenario, is there a warranty that the sum of the loaded amount of A and the loaded amount of B will be right (in some connection) if a transfer between A and B is started (in a different connection) between the read of A and the read of B? Would Entity Framework be able to solve this case in some way?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in solution in EF is client-side [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency).  On update EF will build a query that ensures that the row to be updated has not been changed since it was read.

> Properties configured as concurrency tokens are used to implement
> optimistic concurrency control: whenever an update or delete operation
> is performed during SaveChanges, the value of the concurrency token on
> the database is compared against the original value read by EF Core.
>
> If the values match, the operation can complete. If the values do not
> match, EF Core assumes that another user has performed a conflicting
> operation and aborts the current transaction.

You can also opt in to [Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) at whatever isolation level you choose, which may provide similar protections.  Or use [Raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) queries with lock hints for your target database.